# Relative copy conditional formatting that references other worksheet

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a group of worksheets, one of which has 'default' values while the others should only have values if they differs from the default worksheet.

To facilitate this, I want to use conditional formatting to change the color of a cell if its value matches the value of the cell in the same position on the default sheet.

I have this formula in the Conditional Formatting 'custom formula is' field:

```
=match(C4,indirect("Default!C4"),0)
```

This works well for cell C4, but I want to apply this same conditional formatting to all the cells in a range, and I can't find any way to accomplish this short of manually changing the referenced cell for each and every cell in the document.

Any help?

Comment: Ideally, yes.  It should be something I can apply across a range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
=IF(INDIRECT("R"&ROW()&"C"&COLUMN(),FALSE)=INDIRECT("Default!R"&ROW()&"C"&COLUMN(),FALSE),TRUE,FALSE)
```

It's not exactly concise, but it works.

Comment: And if you only need the formatting to be applied if the cells are not empty:
=AND(IF(INDIRECT("R"&ROW()&"C"&COLUMN(),FALSE)=INDIRECT("Default!R"&ROW()&"C"&COLUMN(),FALSE),TRUE,FALSE),NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("R"&ROW()&"C"&COLUMN(),FALSE))))

Answer (score 0):

Promoting [pnuts' comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/70545/relative-copy-conditional-formatting-that-references-other-worksheet?rq=1#comment58926_70546) to an answer: the custom formula

```
=A1<>indirect("Another Sheet!R"&row()&"C"&column(), 0)
```

will apply formatting to all cells in a range (such as A1:Z, etc) that you provide in the conditional formatting dialog.

Explanation:  "0" indicates notation in R1C1 format (available only in new Google Sheets), the concatenated string computes such notation for a cell to which we compare. This comparison command is pretty slow, so you may want to restrict the range to a part of worksheet that's of current interest.